# UWP hosted web app for a localhost web app

Tags: uwp, localhost, hosted-app

I'm trying to create a hosted web app for Windows 10 for a web app hosted on the local machine (localhost), but the resulting windows 10 app is always empty (it shows a blue screen with a big white box with a cross in the middle).

I followed [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2015/11/27/bringing-asp-net-website-to-run-as-a-windows-10-app-and-access-camera-using-uwp-api/) tutorial to create the web hosted app.
The web app at localhost is a .NET MVC 4 web app with HTML5, CSS3 and Bootstrap.
And here is my manifest:

[image]

[image]

Not quite impressive... but i think that should work... while it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, and based on my experience, it seems that if the app doesn't get past the splash screen it's because there are no valid Content URIs that can be used.

These should be specified in the package.appxmanifest file.

[image: Content URIs section of the package.appxmanifest file]

There are a couple of potential gotchas

1. If you've added an extra entry it will default to a WinRT Access
   value of 'None' and so won't be used. Change this if it's the case.
2. Visual Studio seems to cache the contents of the appxmanifest file and 
   doesn't pick up changes immediately. Even if the changes have been saved to 
   disk and even if you rebuild the project. Closing
   and restarting VS seems to be the only way to flush this.

Comment: about the 2. ... restarting VS, rebooting my environment, or even creating a new project does not seem to update the appxmanifest contents sent to my remove device (an xbox one). Did it happen to you? I tried to delete the /bin folder with no success.

Comment: @vgrafe You may need to rebuild to force the new manifest to be redeployed. If you can't delete the /bin folder it's probably because something is holding a reference to a file within it

Comment: I just found out - the xbox cache won't clear, unless I turn it off and unplug power cord for a minute or so. Thanks for the reply!